# php remove characters from string - at the same position from the last removed

Tags: php, string, character

I will start with an example to explain better what I mean. I have the following string:

```
$str = "x' OR firstname LIKE '%Carla%";
$returned_str = chunk_split($str,1,".");
echo $returned_str;
```

This string is being returned like this:

```
x.'. .O.R. .f.i.r.s.t.n.a.m.e. .L.I.K.E. .'.%.C.a.r.l.a.%.
```

So now what I am trying to do is to reverse what I did with `chunk_split()`.
I want to remove the dots, but only the ones that are precedent of one character, and to do this successfully, the solution shouldn't remove original dots of the string.

So this string:

> My name is Fábio. I like PHP. I am Portuguese.

In the end shouldn't end like this:

> My name is Fábio I like PHP I am Portuguese

Comment: What is the use case for this? What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: stopping sql injection trough my own way..

Comment: http://www.unixwiz.net/techtips/sql-injection.html

Comment: Simply loop over the string and remove every other character (2nd, 4th, 6th etc). I am not sure how are you going to prevent a SQL injection with this. I would advise against using any hackish approaches and just use PDO instead.

Comment: i do not agree, sql injection is all about preventing the sql from reading text as code, and this does cover every attempt to do it!

Comment: how does inserting dots & then removing them is preventing sql injection ? please explain

Comment: dots will go to sql with all fields (email, name, passwords...), but if i want to print the name for example i need to remove the dots in an efficient way (fast script)

Comment: it's good to be creative but it's good too to keep perspective on solutions you invent especially when many other solution exists already... here, first inconvenience i see is that you are doubling the size of your db (talk about "fast script" lol); then `OR firstname LIKE ` is part of your query, not the post or the get... it doesn't make any sense to save  query in the db, or does it ?

Comment: that is not a big problem to have a double size database when the info will not be to big like names.. i think its better than always be uncertain about security. you mean O.R. .f.i.r.s.t.n.a.m.e. .L.I.K.E. ? simple text... But although i do not agree with you i appreciate the alert :)

Comment: "(talk about "fast script" lol)" ? lol -- PDO is not to fast too!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use str_split for convert your string to an array.
Then, you recreate your string in concatenating a char on two (modulo 2 for example).

Edit: or just :

```
$reverse = '';
for ($i=0; $i < strlen($returned_str); $i += 2)
    $reverse .= $returned_str[$i];
```

Comment: can you give me an example ?

Comment: You can just use strlen even... : $reverse = '';
for ($i=0; $i < strlen($returned_str); $i += 2)
    $reverse .= $returned_str[$i];

Answer (score -2):

you can use the explode function 
$x=explode('.','your string here');//it returns an array

Comment: but $x=explode('.','your string here'); will remove the original dots of the string too

Comment: i dont know if this would work but if you could put a escape character before (\.) or  use addslashes and then apply the chunk_split it might work

Comment: i want to use the minimal characters (only dots) to be efficient. And the approach to solve this problem should not combine previous characters because a user can enter something like +. and if i try to match that, then those characters wont be in the printed text

Comment: before printing you can use strip_slashes function to get your original text back i use add_slashes while inserting and strip_slashes while displaying my way to handle sql injections works fine u should give it a try

Comment: Ohh, you mean trying something else separated from my idea. But add_slashes and strip_slashes are already known of that used alone or with other layers of security that are always not to safe! There is always gaps!